# Reading xml with libxml2 in C

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

I have the following XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<category>
    <data>
        <ca0>100</ca0>
        <ca1>Spielfilm</ca1>
        <ca2>Spielfilm</ca2>
    </data>
    <data>
        <ca0>200</ca0>
        <ca1>Serie</ca1>
        <ca2>Serie</ca2>
    </data>
</category>
```

I am developing a C program, which should read this XML file and transfer it into a MySQL database. I have looked at several examples but I didn't succeed.

To read the XML I use:

```
reader = xmlReaderForFile("/tmp/category.xml", NULL, 0);
xmlTextReaderRead(reader);
name = xmlTextReaderName(reader);
if (!xmlStrcmp(name, (const xmlChar *) "category"))
{
    xmlTextReaderRead(reader);
    name = xmlTextReaderName(reader);
    if(!xmlStrcmp(name, (const xmlChar*) "data")) {
        xmlTextReaderRead(reader);
        name = xmlTextReaderName(reader);
    }
}
```

I expected that `name` contained "ca0", but it is empty. Why?

Comment: Please show what you've written already, this way we can see which part of the API are unclear for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the node type is `XNT_Element`, `XNT_EndElement`, or `XNT_Text`. It could be the `XNT_Whitespace` type after any of the element which followed by an indent.

ps: I don't think you can actually get the `<data>` element as the sequence you pasted above. You probably  get the first `XNT_Whitespace` right after `<category>`.